# zpool upgrade planning (time, I/O usage, etc.)

Tags: opensolaris, zfs, maintenance

I recently upgraded our SXCE svn_72 box to OpenSolaris 2009.06 (snv_111b). It wants to me to upgrade my zpool to the latest version now.

We need to plan upfront for things like `zpool scrub` because of the amount of time it takes and the IO intensive nature of the command. Our virtual machine disks on it grind to a halt.

Should I expect the same for `zpool upgrade`? We have about 1.5TB spread across two raidz1's made up of 5 and 7 disks respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `zpool upgrade` isn't as IO intensive as `zpool scrub` since it doesn't have to touch the all the data in the pool. It just lets you use new features (which changes some on disk ZFS data structures in a backward incompatible way).

You can expect the upgrade of 1.5 TB to take about 1 second.

Comment: Agree zpool upgrade is very quick...almost instant.

Comment: Only took a second or two. No impact. Thx guys!